Unable to deserialise ProblemDetails returned from Webapi
I have two micro services written in C# running on .NET 8.0.

WebApiOne has a GlobalHandler that implements IExceptionHandler that returns the following:
var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
                         {
                             Status = statusCode,
                             Title = title,
                             Extensions = new Dictionary<string, object?>
                                  {
                                      { "errors", new[] { errors?.ToArray()} },
                                      { "traceId", traceId }
                                  }
                         };

httpContext.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;

await httpContext.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync<ProblemDetails>(problemDetails, cancellationToken);




In WebApiTwo, I call WebApiOne and if unsuccessful, I deserialise the response.Content to a ProblemDetails, like so:
ProblemDetails problem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProblemDetails>(response.Content);

This was unsuccessful! When I inspect the response.Content, I see the following json returned


{
"problemDetails":{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.5","title":"Not Found","status":404,"errors":["Company xxxxx not found."],"traceId":"00-e30d5f33ee2885874ab4faf827e0f660-117cedba6f2a3368-00"},"contentType":"application/problem+json","statusCode":404
}

I was expecting ProblemDetails not a property  called "problemDetails", is this normal behaviour?
If not, is there a solution to this?, I want to deserialise to ProblecDetals object

According to your description, I write a test demo at my side, it works well, since you don't provide how you create the exception hanlder and how you use httpclient to call this web api, you could refer to my codes and test with my codes.
My test demo as below:
ProblemDetails
public class ProblemDetails
{
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }


    public Dictionary<string, object?> Extensions { get; set; }
}

CustomExceptionHandler:
public class CustomExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    private readonly ILogger<CustomExceptionHandler> logger;
    public CustomExceptionHandler(ILogger<CustomExceptionHandler> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
    public async ValueTask<bool> TryHandleAsync(
        HttpContext httpContext,
        Exception exception,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
        {
            Status = "404",
            Title = "test",
            Extensions = new Dictionary<string, object?>
            {
                                  { "errors", new[] { "Company xxxxx not found." } },
                { "traceId", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }
                              }
        };

        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;

        await httpContext.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync<ProblemDetails>(problemDetails, cancellationToken);

        return false;
    }
}

My client codes:
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7231/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/problem+json"));
        var url = "WeatherForecast";
        var response =   client.GetAsync(url).Result;
        var responseBody =   response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProblemDetails>(responseBody);

Result:

